# Undefinded symbols when linking OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, linker

I'm trying to link static libraries for the OpenCV library into my project, yet I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__ZN2cv9ExceptionC1EiRKSsS2_S2_i", referenced from:
      __ZL16icvGenerateQuadsPP8CvCBQuadPP10CvCBCornerP12CvMemStorageP5CvMati in libopencv_calib3d.a(calibinit.o)
      _cvFindChessboardCorners in libopencv_calib3d.a(calibinit.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no ideas what that symbol "ZN2cv9ExceptionC1EiRKSsS2_S2_i" should be, that string of Letters found in any source or header file I used to build the static libraries.

Could anyone who's more experienced with the linker explain these errors to me?

EDIT: 01.07. haven't solved this yet, just opted out of checkerboard-detection with calib3d and went for a less complicated circle detection using features2D that gives no linking error.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you put OpenCV libs in wrong order. Try the following order in your link list:

> opencv_contrib opencv_legacy opencv_videostab opencv_photo opencv_stitching opencv_objdetect opencv_video opencv_ml opencv_calib3d opencv_features2d opencv_highgui opencv_flann opencv_imgproc opencv_core

Comment: Tried reordering in Project Build Phases list, both the following orders didn't work: "[..]-framework CrashReporter -framework GameKit -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_ml -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_flann -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -o [..]" and "[..]-framework GameKit -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_contrib -o[..]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `c++filt` to unmangle the undefined symbol to find the actual function name.

```
$ c++filt.exe __ZN2cv9ExceptionC1EiRKSsS2_S2_i
cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)
```

Then you'll have to identify which source file contains this function and link in the library corresponding to that.

Comment: Unfortunately I can see no particular function names in the so unmangled symbol...

Comment: The library that contains the missing function is `libopencv_core.a`.

Comment: That's the first library I linked.. well now I gave up using legacy/calib3d and use a circle-detecting way, using features2d.a. (features2s, imgproc, objdetect and core lnk in fine)